# How to override reddits .media-preview to show full quality images uploaded there with adaptive size corresponding to browser window?

Tags: css, webkit, stylesheet, reddit

See the image gallery: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ncov.jpg

Watch the post: https://www.reddit.com/r/CallOfDutyWorldWarTwo/comments/6fyhab/the_big_edge_interview_with_shgames/

I have managed to set a fixed size, which blows up the "preview (That is images uploaded to reddit, videos from YouTube, imgur galleries etc. media preview)" before you click it. As you can see; the "higher" the image are the smaller it gets in width.

The ultimate solution would have the full scale image shown with 100% width of the post, not a thumbnail.

Here is the what I have:

```
.media-preview {
max-width: none !important;
overflow: auto;
position: relative;
}


.media-preview {
max-width: 710px !important;
overflow: auto;
position: relative;
}

.media-preview .media-preview-content {
float: left;
max-width: 710px;
width: 450px;
}
```

There has to be a smart way to get it to display better than what I'm capable of.

Thanks for viewing and hopefully replying with an answer.

Comment: Is that a working example? If so then consider posting to codereview.stackexchange.com for help shortening it

Comment: To get it to display a fixed size on images and media, yes. It doesnt fetch the full quality image and blocks thumbnails, and it doesnt adjust to the width of the post, instad of the height.